# How can I output static text under the "Short Description" area in Woocommerce for items in a specific category?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a shop with several categories, most of which are held on-site, but there's a category where the items are then sourced upon request. For this category (and children), I'd like to output some text directly below the 'short_description' asking that the client contact us for availability prior to purchase.

It is important that it only shows in that category and its children categories, in this case 'grow-shop'.

I've attempted to use some other code found on stackoverflow to get text to be output for a specific category.

```
<div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description">
    <?php echo $short_description; // WPCS: XSS ok. ?>
    <?php global $product;
     if( has_term( 'grow-shop', 'product_cat', $product->id ) ) {
      echo "Please note: This item is not held in stock. Please contact us for availability before purchase.";
     } ?>
 </div>
```

So far, I'm not able to achieve any accurate output. Echoing text is fine, but I don't have the right query to determine if it falls within the grow-shop category and its subcategories I feel.

Comment: Does the product actually have the category `grow-shop` assigned, or _just_ one of its child categories?

Comment: I see that most products were actually not uploaded into the grow-shop category but just the children, though with that said I changed the category of the product to be associated with "grow shop" directly, and still don't have it displaying. Would there be a way to change it so that I can just list all the children in the query? Or maybe even a simpler way.

EDIT: Can confirm that when I change the 'grow-shop' to the name of a child category it works. How would I query multiple children in that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modified code as below.

```
// If a product in the 'grow-shop' category is being viewed...

if ( is_product() && has_term( 'grow-shop', 'product_cat' ) ) {
    echo "Please note: This item is not held in stock. Please contact us for 
    availability before purchase.";
}
// for multiple categories 
if(is_product_category( array( 'grow-shop', 'reflectors', 'nutrients' )))
{
    echo "Please note: This item is not held in stock. Please contact us for 
    availability before purchase.";
}
// for apply same condition as or concept 
if( is_product_category( 'category1-slug' ) || is_product_category( 
     'category2-slug' ) ) 
{
     echo "Please note: This item is not held in stock. Please contact us 
     for availability before purchase.";
}
```

Comment: Let me know answer is helpful or not

Comment: Thank you, is there any way to have it apply to the children of grow-shop too. I see the data capturer only placed them in the children categories of grow-shop. Alternatively, is there a way for me to modify that to provide several categories. For instance, grow-shop has "reflectors", "nutrients", "extraction" as children, where the items are placed in. Could I amend the query to run numerous 'has_term' values?

Comment: Just update answer you will add multiple categories in array as above code

Comment: Let me know answer is helpful or not

Comment: Appreciate your help. The single query works perfectly, but when I try use the array for multiple categories, I don't get the text output anymore.

Comment: I think I found the problem. It is only showing on products where there is already a short description, I may need to move the query up outside of the conditional query on the short description.

Comment: ok just updated answer and let me know still any issue and give your feeedback

Comment: @xmesox Please let me know answer is helpful

Answer (score 1):

Just add the follows code snippet -

```
function woocommerce_short_description( $excerpt ){
    global $post;
    $cats_slugs = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'slugs' ) );
    if( in_array( 'grow-shop', $cats_slugs ) ){ 
        $excerpt .= " Please note: This item is not held in stock. Please contact us for availability before purchase.";
    }
    return $excerpt;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'woocommerce_short_description', 99 );
```